# .htaccess rewrite index.php and pages.php?page=value to .html

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, redirect, mod-rewrite

I'm trying to figure out how i can redirect my index.php to index.html and also my pages.php?page=value to value.html
I can make it one by one but i can't do it together

Could you please help me to solve this?
I'm new in .htaccess

Here what i've tried:

```
Options +FollowSymLinks 
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^([^/]*)\.html$ pages.php?page=$1 [L]
RewriteRule ^(.*)\.html$ $1.php [NC]
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: You have to decide. Either you rewrite `foo.html` to `pages.php?page=foo` our `foo.php` - you can't do both at the same time.

Comment: Thanks, i thought there is something that can skip index.php from the first rule but then i need to make it in anoher way...